# AJAX request to php for getting the list of the file on the server in the specified directory sent by post/get (WITHOUT JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a table in html with only 1 column: My FILES.

What I'm trying to reach: (a file explorer of a folder in the server)

---

When the page loads in body onload i call an ajax function that add a row for every file in my  directory on the server. (shows the content of a predefined folder)

every rows has the name of the file and two kind of icons: one for simple file, another one click-able for directory. A user can click on the directory and another AJAX call is made to update the content of the table for showing the content of the clicked folder.

---

My only experience with ajax of yesterday was to call a php script that update a field in the page notifying the user if a username is available or not for registration purpose. I made this with POST and responseText AJAX format.

I don't know now for the file list what is best if responseXML or responseText and you have suggestion about an easy way to do this??? (it's for educational purpose, just for make you know)

Answer (score 0):

JSON is the easiest way to go since you can use the buildin [jsonencode function](http://www.php.net/json_encode) provided by php if you have your php objects ready. Then you use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the client  and you can use the resultinng javascript object directly in the javascript that updates your page